# how to find number of paths between 2 nodes of a certain length

Tags: algorithm, matrix, graph-algorithm

given G graph ' and a matrix of nodes , how can i find number of paths between 2 given nodes of a certain length ?
i've thought of multiping the matrix k times and then find the Ak[i,j] but i don't know to build the algorithm , or is it the best solution when it comes to complexity ?

Comment: You mention in your question the correct solution to your problem, are you asking how to multiply a matrix by itself?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. What is this matrix, how does it look like? Can you give a small example?

Comment: @user3483203 That gives he number of walks though, not paths

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find all the paths between two nodes of length `k`, just multiply the adjacency matrix by itself `k` times.

The reason for this is simple:
If there is an edge `ij` and an edge `js`, then there will be a path `is` through `j`. The entries `ii` are the degrees of the nodes `i`.

Here is an adjacency matrix for a graph:

```
0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 
1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

Let's say we want to find the number of length 3 paths between Nodes 2 and 5.  For this we need to find `A_3[2, 5]`.

There are plenty of algorithms for matrix multiplication, and certain languages have these built in.

So if our adjancency matrix is called `A`, we want `A * A * A`.

This gives us:

```
2 1 1 2 3 2 1 1 1 0
2 2 2 2 3 2 1 2 1 1
2 1 1 1 3 2 3 3 3 1
2 2 2 2 4 3 3 3 3 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 3 8 3 6
0 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 0 2
0 0 0 2 0 0 1 5 1 6
1 0 0 3 1 0 0 1 0 3
1 0 0 3 1 0 0 1 0 3
2 1 1 3 3 1 1 0 1 1
```

When we find `A_3[2, 5]` we are given 2, which is the number of length 3 paths between the 2 nodes.